# Better way to importing packages in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i could import every package which is located directory level below:

```
import { RegisterComponent } from './register-component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login-component';
import { EmailComponent } from './email-component';
```

But it's too much work, so is there any easier way to import them let's say in one line?

Comment: If you are using some sort of IDE/editor like VSCode you can install auto importers plugins, makes it easy without typing it out the imports.

Answer (score 1):

You can use what are called "barrel" files.  Create an index.ts file where you want to import from, i.e. `components/` and add the following:

```
export * from './some-component';
export * from './some-other-component';
export * from './another-component';
```

From there, you can import like so:

```
import { SomeComponent, SomeOtherComponent, AnotherComponent } from '../components'
```

Comment: Thanks for good idea, btw microsoft announced new feature: "import * as React from "react";"